# Coda slider conflicting

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery coda slider 2.0 on website on all the pages it works fine like http://www.virtualmob.co.uk/solutions.html

but when i add a gallery on gallery page http://www.virtualmob.co.uk/gallery.html

it conflicts with web.js & give me a below mentioned error on browser:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'removeClass' of null
>
> on line number  jquery.coda-slider-2.0.js:9

I tried **$.noConflict();** on the top like i mentioned below,

```
$.noConflict();
$(function(){
// Remove the coda-slider-no-js class from the body
$("body").removeClass("coda-slider-no-js");
// Preloader
$(".coda-slider").children('.panel').hide().end().prepend('<p class="loading">Loading...<br /><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading..." /></p>');
});`
```

but still it not works & shows me a below error

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function
```

I also tried to add this on web.js but that also did not help me

**Kindly guide how can this remove conflict can remove??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `$` in `$.noConflict`, if you want to avoid conflict, use `jQuery` keyword instead of the `$` and save the returned value in a variable:

```
var $ref = jQuery.noConflict();
$ref(function(){
  // ... 
})
```

You can also put your code in a closure:

```
(function($){
    $(function(){
       $('body').foo()
    })
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

For other users, the below mention it solved:

i use the line mention below like guided in the above post

```
(function($){
    $(function(){
       $('body').foo()
    });
})(jQuery);
```

then i move the `$.document.ready` script which is on my html page to intiate script to the js file & it works. :)